# How can i rebuild only one property of specific widget without to rebuild the whole widget using flutter_riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

i am using `flutter_riverpod` provider , and i have `Listview.builder` that contains big widgets on it's `return`. i am wrapping every widget into Consumer for better `performance`
like following

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: finalResultsForChat.length,
itemBuilder: (context, int index)  {
 return Column(
    children[
      Consumer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
       String item1 = ref.watch(item1);
       return Widget1() ;
      }
     Consumer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
       String item1 = ref.watch(item1);
       return Widget2() ;
      }
       Consumer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
       String item1 = ref.watch(item1);
       return Widget2() ;
       // And many Consumer widgets .. etc
      }
     )
     )
     )
    ]
  );
}
```

Now i have the following `method` for providing the `listview.builder` the wanted data from `Firstore`

```
List finalResultsForChat = [];
Future getData()async{
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.negId).collection("chats1")
.get().then((data) {
  finalResultsForChat.addAll(data.docs);

  // after i add data so here i am refreshing every widget Consumer depending on which 
  //Consumer will hold the specific data and i am doing good here 
   ref.refresh(item1);
   .....etc
});
```

but the challenge that i face is that i need also to rebuild the `listView.builder` for
`finalResultsForChat` List that `listView.builder` has it in it's `itemcount`
and to solve it i can also wrap `listView.builder` into `Consumer` but if i do it it sound
so dirty way to me because others `Consumers` that i add them into `listView.builder's  return` will be making no sense ..
So How can i only refresh the `itemcount` without to refresh the whole `listView.builder`

Note: all my work into `StfulWidget`

any suggestions are most welcome guys

Answer (score 0):

If the finalResultsForChat change you must rebuild the listView.builder. But not all the widget within will be rebuild. Have you check a print in the build methode of one widget child?

```
return ListView(
      children: finalResultsForChat
          .map((chat) => Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) {
                // String item1 = ref.watch(item1);
                return Container();
              }))
          .toList(),
    );
```

Comment: if i did not misunderstand you it is do rebuild all

Comment: Check  if any rebuild occured in your widget by a print in the build methode.